# Resample time based column array as per sampling time in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to run a simulation with sample time of

```
tsample = 0.01 ; % seconds
```

I have a table such as below

[image]

I need to resample each column in input table such that value of the input Time vector gets equally spaced based on tsample values.

For the [Time] column I achieved this by following code

```
    simTime         = max(tests.(test_names{i}).Times);   % Seconds

    % Interpolate the time and frequency values as per sample time
    numSteps        = simTime/tsample;    
    time            = tsample * [0:(numSteps-1)]';
```

What I need to do now is resize the frequency (f) values such that it shall be filled with previous values until a new value is found in column;

| Time | f |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 50 |
| .... | 50 |
| 4.99 | 50 |
| 5.00 | 49.65 |
| .... | 49.65 |
| 19.99 | 49.65 |
| 20.00 | 49.80 |

I am confused whether I should use **fillmissing** or **resample** or **interp1**.
The examples I am following for these seem kind of different than what I wish to achieve here.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
I tried experimenting with more examples for **interp1** and this solved my issue.

```
freq = interp1(tests.Times, tests.fHz, time, 'previous');
```

I was earlier unaware of the 'previous' option
Should have searched the documentation more extensively.